# NSDates changed in UITableView Header

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

So I am using an array of dates as Section Headers in my UITableView. The dates of my data in the arrays is as follows

```
07/12/2012
07/13/2012
07/14/2012
```

But when I run the app the section headers are all moved back one day so they are as follows:

```
07/11/2012
07/12/2012
07/13/2012
```

What gives?  The data I am pulling from the server is specific to timeZone. We know when our app will be used and on what day (think traveling circus).

I am sure this has to do with NSTimeZone, so I tried the following, which did not work.

```
self.sectionDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.sectionDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[self.sectionDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[self.sectionDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

Anyone know have a solution?

Comment: are these dates possibly UTC dates?  e.g. does setting your timezone to GMT resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the dates to UTC and it fixed the issue.